# How could you highlight the path to a treeview node similar to XYPlorer

Tags: wpf

I want to highlight a treeview node similar to how XYPlorer does it

[image]

Any ideas how I could do this in WPF?

Comment: You find the corresponding item in the `TreeView` and select it. How to do this depends on your code. Please share an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for further help.

Comment: The question is not how to select a specific node, but how to highlight the path to the node (green highlighting above). XYPlorer is an application which I do not have the source code to, which is why I asked how it might be done.